# How to progress to next window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm sorry for the vague wording in this question.
I've created a login system with Tkinter but am not sure how to create a new window for the main menu of the app I want to make.
I've tried opening a new window but that still leaves the login window open and if I attempt to delete it with the .destroy command it shuts down the whole thing.
is there a way to completely refresh/open a new window?

Comment: Use `Toplevel`  and `root.withdraw()` to hide the window meanwhile.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering.

Comment: Or create a new `tk.Tk` and call `old_root.destroy()` on the old one that you aren't going to use. If you call `old_root.destroy()` first, it will switch the default tkinter window so you shouldn't have any problems using the new window.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to completely refresh/open a new window?

The simplest solution is to put all of your "windows" inside frames -- login window is all inside a single frame, the main window is all inside a single frame, etc.

Then, when you're ready to switch from one to the other, just destroy the login frame and create the main window frame, all without having to destroy the main window.

A similar solution is to simply delete all of the children in the root window and then add the new widgets. It's easiest if everything is in a single frame, but you can destroy all of the widgets one by one by calling `winfo_children` on the root window and iterating over the results.

Comment: Some times that isn't a good idea especially when you want to bind the root to a key press (for example `"<Return>"`).

Comment: @TheLizzard: yes, every design decision has tradeoffs.

Comment: If you destroy the old window, it will be as if you just imported tkinter for the first time. Therefore, you can just create a new window. I find that its the most intuitive way. Also it isn't going to have any side effects from what I tested.

Comment: @TheLizzard: _"If you destroy the old window, it will be as if you just imported tkinter for the first time. "_ - that's not 100% true. Global variables that may have been created before will still be around.

Comment: As I said from what I tested (the global varaibles like `_default_root`) are reset to their original value.

Comment: @TheLizzard: yes, tkinter variales will be reset, but not other variables. You implied _all_ data is reset, and that's not true.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `old_root.destroy()` and that will close the old window. It will also reset all of the global variables in tkinter so it will be as if you just imported tkinter for the first time. So you can create a new tkinter window using `tk.Tk()`. I find this approach more intuitive and easier to understand/implement.

**Edit:** You need to first pull the data out of your entries/other widgets before you call `old_root.destroy()` otherwise the data will be deleted as well.

Comment: Normally you build levels of your application and you may want to use the data of your login in your further application. I can't share your point of view

Comment: @Atlas435 that is why you first pull the data out of the entries and then destroy the window. If you have the data in python variables, it isn't going to be effected by the destruction of the window. I will edit my answer to make that clearer. Also all of the bindings for the old window would be called anymore.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. But still, I doupt that this a valid choice. Just imagine a huge application and you just want to logout and login with another user. You would need to destroy your application and reload all of it, just for changing the user,

Comment: @Atlas435 otherwise all of the bindings will still be there. Imagine if OP decided to bind to `"<Return>"` so the user doesn't have to press the Log in button. If he uses `old_root.bind("<Return>", login_function)` and the user presses `"<Return>"` after he is already logged in then his program will crash (if he is using BryanOakley's method). Also reloading the screen shouldn't take that much time in a well designed program. Also also most programs only have 1 or 2 screen and the user switches between them.

Comment: @Atlas435 also `old_root.after` scripts would be cancelled if you use `old_root.destroy()`. Also the time to create a new window is `0.170` seconds on my computer. That delay isn't even noticeable.

Comment: I would have bind the `'<Return>'`-Key to the Entry, which is wether destroyed or havent the keyboard focus anymore. I draw my widgets by myself and also drawing pictures for a nice looking GUI. Thats the reason I use threading and it still need some time to init all of my application. I dont call your solution as bad advice, I'm just thinking there are some issues for programs like mine.

Comment: @Atlas435 if you have more than 1 entry it's easier to bind using `old_root.bind(...)`. Usually its a bad idea to have tkinter in different threads. I have used this multiple times without any problems and I can't see any problems with it. It is possible to move the new window to the position where the old window was and creating a new window only costs around 0.2 sec (worst case). It also stops all `.after` scripts and removes all bindings.